# Only one browser running with selenium Grid while other are launched inactive

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am running my tests on selenium Grid.I am facing a problem like only one browser(firefox) is fed commands b server.Other browsers launched just load the URL and stay still.No activity happens in other browsers.
By similar posts I figured out that I am using a static Selenium instance .

```
public static Selenium selenium=null;
public WebDriver driver;
```

and I am obtaining a webDriverBackedSelenium intance, as my all scripts were coded to work with Selenium RC years back.

```
 driver= new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeurl.concat(port).concat("/wd/hub")), 
 selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, url);
```

Now, I have a lot of static methods,As I make selenium instance Non-static,my tests are flooded with java errors.What possible solution can be here.

Comment: You do not want to hear it, but the solution will be *refactor your code*

Comment: Can I find some solution using ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage Class.

Comment: @VirendraJoshi It depends on how you had been organising the Framework flow

Comment: @HarshaVardhan Konakanchi ...Or can it done using ThreadLocal objects and anything else.

Comment: @Slanec can u help me in this ...Thnaks